# How can I use trigonometric functions and tick labels with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  samples=100,
  ymax=5,legend pos=north east,
  legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot[forget plot,cyan,domain=0.001:8] {abs(log10(x))};
\addplot[forget plot,red!70!black,domain=-2:4] {2+exp(abs(x))};
\addplot[green,thick,domain=-2:3] {exp(x)};
\addlegendentry{$e^{x}$};
\node[pin={90:$f(x)=\lvert\log x\rvert$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{2,log10(2)}) {};
\node[pin={0:$f(x)=e^{x}$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{1,exp(1)}) {};
\node[anchor=north west] 
  at (axis description cs:0,0.5)
  {$\lvert e^{x}\rvert$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have used these code to generate the curves. It shown to me like:

[image: output]

But after making change in the function abs(log(x)) into sin(x), like in the following codes,

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  samples=100,
  ymax=5,legend pos=north east,
  legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot[forget plot,cyan,domain=0.001:8] {sin(x)};
\addplot[forget plot,red!70!black,domain=-2:4] {2+exp(abs(x))};
\addplot[green,thick,domain=-2:3] {exp(x)};
\addlegendentry{$e^{x}$};
\node[pin={90:$f(x)=\lvert\log x\rvert$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{2,log10(2)}) {};
\node[pin={0:$f(x)=e^{x}$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{1,exp(1)}) {};
\node[anchor=north west] 
  at (axis description cs:0,0.5)
  {$\lvert e^{x}\rvert$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got the image as

[image]

**Requirements**

(1) I should have my sin x graph with this graphs.

(2) My x-axis tick must have `$-\pi, \frac \pi 2 ,...$` means I want radian measure ticks.

How do I do this.?

Comment: you need to have `sin(deg(x))`

Comment: For 1): `sin` assumes degrees, use `sin(deg(x))`. For 2), see if [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34939),  [Graphing trigonometric functions, axes labeled with tick marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195006) or [Locating tick marks at integral multiples of pi/2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249953) help.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253738/trigonometric-tikz, although the other links may be better. However, this one includes an answer I wrote which includes references for relevant questions and for pages from the manual. Basically, it has these because I was figuring out how to do things more-or-less from scratch. So I thought the commented references might be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides fixing it by writing as `sin(x)`, you can switch from degrees to radian with pgfplots 1.11 and newer:

```
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad}
```

After adding it to your drawing, I got the sine function nicely displayed:

[image: sine function output]

This was first mentioned on [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/) by the `pgfplots` author in an answer to "[Kann man bei pgfplots die Argumente trigonometrischer Funktionen von Grad auf Radiant umstellen](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/6952/kann-man-bei-pgfplots-die-argumente-trigonometrischer-funktionen-von-grad-auf-radiant-umstellen)".

Furthermore, you could get radian in ticks by

```
  xtick = {-1.5707, 0, ..., 6.28318},
  xticklabels = {$-\frac{\pi}{2}$, 0, 
    $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$}
```